# Google maps zoom control position on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to set the zoom control position on mobile devices for google maps?

```
zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
```

works only for desktop, but doesn't work on mobile (the control is always in the bottom left corner)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfbowz8f/2/

Comment: Have you tried disabling the default UI? I didn't test that but it might be worth to give it a try: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultUI

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks, but i don't want to disable (hide) the zoom control, i want to just move it from bottom left to top left corner

Comment: Read again. 1) Disable the default UI. 2) Add each control manually.